# mysql views vs nested selects

Tags: mysql, database, view

Is there any downside to using views to represent nested selects in a complex query?

For example,

```
select * from (select * from B)A
```

vs

define viewB as:

```
select * from B
```

Run the main query:

```
select * from viewB
```

Creating views makes things easier to debug and read, but i'm worried it's taking longer to run queries that are trying to join across multiple views at once, versus building one giant sql statement.

Comment: You should look at the results of EXPLAIN on these statements.

Comment: It might depend on the datbase (both database provider and individual database design) as well as the view designs. At that simple level I would not expect much of a differnce, but once the views get complicated and call other complicated views, they can become horrendous performance hogs in some datbases (generating over a milion ros for a final result set of 3 for instance) and they areMUCH much harder to maintain. JUst try to fix a problem inteh first view when you have to track through 17 other views to find it to pick a not random example for a long time ago.

Comment: Also never ever use select * in production code espcially if you have joins.